# Get substitutions from s/pattern/sub/g

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I'm trying to get the content that was replaced (actually, removed) from the substitution function.

For example:

```
my $line = q{hello "my" friend "how" are 'you'};
$line =~ s/("[^"]*"|'[^']*')//g; # Removing any balanced quotes

# I'd like to print
# "my" "how" 'you'
```

Please be kind, I'm beginning with Perl :-).

Comment: Do you insist of substituting `$line`?

Comment: Yes, although I could do it in two lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `/e` regex modifier to execute code in substitution part, where `$1` is being pushed into `@w` array, and finally replaced by `""` empty string.

```
my @w;
$line =~ s/("[^"]*"|'[^']*')/ push @w,$1; "" /ge;

print "$_\n" for @w;
```

Comment: This seems to work, awesome, thanks. Could you just explain briefly ?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of doing a `global` substitute, you can use a loop and process each substitution:

```
my $line = qq(hello "my" friend "how" are 'you');
print "$1\n" while $line =~ s/("[^"]*"|'[^']*')//;
print "$line\n";
```

*Gives:*

```
"my"
"how"
'you'
hello  friend  are
```

Comment: I like this approach. I've accepted @mpapec's one because he was the first one to answer, however, as a perl beginner, I like this one

Comment: @DCMaxxx If you like it, then give it an upvote, this is a preferred way to show your appreciation.

Comment: Not very efficient, as the replace is unnecessarily restarted from the beginning of the string for each iteration.

Comment: @DCMaxxx: You should accept the answer that you *prefer*. Being first isn't a useful quality in an answer. You can always change the answer that you accept.

Comment: This solution won't work in general, as the search starts from the *beginning* of the string each time. If the change the substitution made could also match the pattern then it will keep replacing the same string over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, using the built-in `@-` and `@+` arrays that hold the offsets of the latest successful match and captures.

It simply finds all the matching substrings, saves them in `@removed` and deletes them using `substr`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = q{hello "my" friend "how" are 'you'};

my @removed;

while ($line =~ /("[^"]*"|'[^']*')/g) {
  push @removed, $1;
  substr $line, $-[0], $+[0] - $-[0], '';
}

print $line, "\n";
print "@removed\n";
```

**output**

```
hello  friend  are 
"my" "how" 'you'
```

Comment: As documented in [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) - search for `@LAST_MATCH_START` or `@-`.